# AEM returning compilation error when using jsp:include

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

Currently using

```
 <cq:include script="/apps/components/list-value.jsp" />
```

but I now need to include a page with param so the counter is limited to within the included page, I am thinking of using:

```
 <jsp:include page="/apps/components/list-value.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="counter" value="${counter + 1}" />
 </jsp:include>
```

but I keep getting compilation error "org.apache.sling.api.SlingException: Exception during response processing"

Is there equivalent cq: function for this?

Comment: is my answer bellow enough to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you get the error because the resource is not found, jsp:resource isn't prepared to get a resource from inside the JCR. Other bad news is that it isn't possible to pass arbitrary parameters to cq:include nor to sling:include (this is other candidate you could use).

One option you have is to set a request attribute and read that inside your script:

```
    <%request.setAtributte("counter", anyvalue);%>
    <cq:include script="/apps/components/list-value.jsp" />
    <%request.removeAttribute("counter"); %>
```

it is pretty ugly, but it is the only way I know if you want to continue using cq:include or sling:include.

other option that just came to my mind is to have the script as a tag file, then you could just pass a parameter to it. First create a tag file in JCR, say it will be stored at '/path/to/the/dir/with/tag/files/list-value.tag'. Then you can import and use it (note the '/WEB-INF/tags' prefix, it is important):

```
    <%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags/path/to/the/dir/with/tag/files" %>
    <t:list-value counter=${counter + 1} />
```

as a last option, you could rewrite your code in a way that you don't need to pass parameters to the script.

Comment: Thanks, I actually tried to render a report dynamically and the counter is for indentation (depending on the depth). If I have 2 headers, each will be indented with same distance. Your answer, removeAttribute, resets the indentation such that the header2 will not have same indentation as header1. I will try the custom taglib solution, not sure this can work since the page makes recursive 'include'.

Comment: Hi, it seems your use case is too complex for the request attibute hack. I think the tag file idea will be better. And tag files does handle recursive calls, I already done that in components of mine. Please, report back your findings.